Elasticsearch via docker-compose - Warning: "this node is locked into cluster UUID..."
I start services in a local cluster via docker compose. Two docker containers are from the example of elasticsearch. I get following error in the console from the elasticsearch:
elasticsearch_instance | 
{
  "@timestamp":"2024-07-11T07:39:09.788Z", 
  "log.level": "WARN", 
  "message": "this node is locked into cluster UUID [fxwqYYLsTdy-C7AmpycuLA] but [cluster.initial_master_nodes] is set to [35794ba3f6c5]; remove this setting to avoid possible data loss caused by subsequent cluster bootstrap attempts", 
  "ecs.version": "1.2.0",
  "service.name": "ES_ECS",
  "event.dataset": "elasticsearch.server",
  "process.thread.name": "main",
  "log.logger": "org.elasticsearch.cluster.coordination.ClusterBootstrapService",
  "elasticsearch.node.name": "35794ba3f6c5",
  "elasticsearch.cluster.name": "docker-cluster"
}

My docker-compose.yml looks like this:
elasticsearch:
  container_name: "elasticsearch_instance"
  image: elasticsearch:8.3.2
  environment:
    - discovery.type=single-node
    - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g
    - xpack.security.enabled=false
  volumes:
    - es_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    - /home/xxx/configs/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro
  ports:
    - 9200:9200
  networks:
    elastic-network:
      aliases:
        - myDb
kibana:
  image: kibana:8.3.2
  ports:
    - target: 5601
      published: 5601
  depends_on:
    - elasticsearch
networks:
  elastic-network:
    driver: bridge

The id "35794ba3f6c5" from above is the ID of the docker container. The ID "fxwqYYLsTdy-C7AmpycuLA" seems to be created by elasticsearch newly at every startup.
The warning implies cluster.initial_master_nodes should not be set to resolve this warning. However, I did not set/apply this setting anywhere.
My elasticsearch.yml looks like this:
$ cat /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
cluster.name: "docker-cluster"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
xpack.security.enabled: false

Does someone know if the solution is to unset cluster.initial_master_nodes, or if there is another solution to this?
The effect I see is that logs do not appear in elasticsearch and I suspect it is because of this warning since it tells to remove this setting to avoid possible data loss.


The solution was to delete all existing docker containers using:
docker container prune

To delete the content of the data folder in
/usr/share/elasticsearch/data


which can be done by changing the name of "es_data" to something else e.g., "es_data1". Otherwise it seems the data is persisted.
